# OnClientClick custom message box before Onclick event handler not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I wanted to have a Custom Message Box OnClientClick . If the User Selects Yes then the Onclick Event handler in the C# code should get trigger. But somehow i am not able to do this using ASP.net and jquery.

**As of now what is happening**

- Only C# code is triggered

**What i was expecting**

- ClientSide Confirmation message  (If User Clicks "YES" ) Then Server-side
  code triggers.

My HTML

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">                                                                
     <div>
       <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="submit" runat="server" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" 
       OnClientClick="if(!ShowDeleteFormConfirmation()) {return false;};" />       
    </div>
</form>
```

Jquery

```
  function ShowDeleteFormConfirmation() {
        var confirmationMessage,
            dlgButtons = {
                "No": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    return false;
                },
                "Yes": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");                        
                    return true;
                }
            };
        confirmationMessage = "This form has already been assigned and will be marked as deleted.";
        var $panelContainer = $("<div>" + confirmationMessage + "</div>").appendTo('body');
        $panelContainer.attr("title", "Confirmation to delete a form");
        var myPos = [$(window).width() / 2 - 100, 50];
        $panelContainer.dialog({
            modal: false,
            draggable: false,
            position: myPos,
            button: dlgButtons
        });
    }
```

C# ////OnClick

````
      protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
             {
                 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Delete button clicked.');", true);
             } ```
````

This is what i wanted to implement.
http://jsfiddle.net/y5z01nbr/

Thanks for having a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, while your code would work if you used "confirm" in the js code, that's because alert() and confirm() HALTS the calling code.

However, today, near ALL WEB code libraries are written to NOT halt, and NOT freeze up the browser. And jQuery is one such system. (it does not HALT the code). While I could introduce the concepts of await - that's becoming a wee bit too complex for this POST.

So, what this means:

```
the jQuery code does NOT halt, 
and thus when you click on the button, 
the client side code runs WITHOUT halting 
and thus the button click (server side code) will 
ALSO run right away - not waiting.
```

So, in the case of a jQuery dialog? You can't HALT the code. this means you have to flip this backwards. The jQuery dialog is to be displayed, AND THEN you have to call/run/click on that server side button. So, you have to add a new button, and use style="display:none" ot the existing button. Then display the dialog, and based on the answer you THEN click on (call) that origional button you have/had now.

The code will thus look like this:

```
<div>
   <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="submit" runat="server" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" 
   Style="display:none" clientIDmode="static" />     

   <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitX" Text="submit" runat="server"  
   clientIDmode="static" OnClientClick="ShowDeleteFormConfirmation();" />     

<\div>
```

So I dropped in another button - no server behind code. Hide first button with display none, and removed the client click. I moved the client click to 2nd button.

Now, we can do this:

```
     dlgButtons = {
            "No": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Yes": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");                        
                $('#btnSubmit').click();
            }
        };
```

So what we do is launch the dialog. And based on yes, then we click our button. If you choose no, then the dialog is dismissed, but no other action need take place.

A a GENERAL hard and fast rule?
Your browser code is RARE these days blocking code - calling a jQuery.ui dialog and in fact most of these newer UI controls? The code does NOT wait, does NOT halt. And this means you can't use the return true/false to control if the server side event stub will run or not (you can use js confirm(), but not jQuery, since it don't wait, nor halt the code).

Comment: Thank you it works. Didn't thought of a hidden placeholder to this. Nice Idea.